# Precheck for long SQL statement

Tags: mysql, parsing

I'm doing a table import using a multiple INSERT (INSERT INTO ... VALUES (1), (2), etc.). Is there a tool that can be used to check if the form of a statement is correct for a given SQL type (ex: MySQL) without necessarily running a query with a database? I just want to check for things like apostrophes, backslashes, etc. in values.

Comment: Are you running this statement through an API, or through a tool?

Comment: is php ok for you? http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Running it through phpMyAdmin. I can use PHP though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool called [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) where you can test this cases

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, there's a parse button next to the execute button.  It is a check icon.

Comment: @eggyal Yes, it was retagged as such. Thank you for this tip though. I sometimes use other database types so this sort of information is welcome.